# customize authentication manager configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have following authentication manager configuration:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" >
        ...
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I need to set `eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication` field to true. Can I do that without rewriting authentication manager configuration with `bean` elements, e.g.

```
<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    ...
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

A common technique is to use a [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) that modifies the bean after it is created.